# Wordpress wp-load.php automatically goes 0 btytes within every 2-3 minutes

Tags: php, wordpress

I saw my website was showing **500 internal server error**.
I tried to debug and found wp-load.php was 0 bytes then I replace with new wp-load.php.
Now my website working fine.
Later, I saw every 2-3 minutes my wp-load.php goes to 0 bytes.

**Please resolve**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your site probably has been hacked.
The attacker is trying to change your wp-load.php via wp-load.php?pubkey=xxxx
Take care of your security.

Answer (score 0):

Its a problem of automatic Wordpress update. Only go to your FTP and find files with 0 bytes, overwrithe these with new WordPress installation from the website.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a wordpress update error because although I replace everything except the wp-content folder and wp-config after 3 minutes, it is deleted again. What happens to this theme or plugin they use to see if we have the error in common
theme: plox
builder: elementor
cache: litespeed cache

no es un error de actualización de wordpress porque aunque sustituyo todo menos la carpeta wp-content y wp-config a los 3 minutos se borra nuevamente .. a los que le pasa esto que tema o plugin usan a ver si tenemos en común el error
tema: plox
contructor: elementor
caché: caché litespeed

Comment: Please post _only_ in English on this site. We have a Spanish version where you are welcome to participate in Spanish: [es.so].

Answer (score 0):

The site has been compromised.  I had a similar issue with a client website where some of their WP Core files kept getting overrwitten and injected with malicious code.  Also the file permissions kept getting set to read only so you couldn't edit the file.  You could delete it and upload a legit copy, only to have it overwritten the moment you reloaded the website.   Look for a script/file outside the webroot (www/public_html) that is executable.